# Maximum call stack size exceeded (Angular8)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm Trying to do the below in Angular, I can't understand where is the problem?
understand that this is a recursive function but in javascript there is a lot of workarounds to solve this, I tried them here but they did not work out
do you have any work around for this?

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  changeImg = () => {
    let i = 0;
    const time = 1000;
    const images = [
      '../../assets/imgs/dashboard_full_1.webp',
      '../../assets/imgs/dashboard_full_2.webp'
    ];
    document.slide.src = images[i];
    if (i < images.length - 1) {
      i++;
    } else {
      i = 0;
    }

    setTimeout(this.changeImg(), time);
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.changeImg();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
setTimeout(this.changeImg(), time);
```

You are *invoking* `this.changeImg()` which invokes `this.changeImg()` which then invokes `this.changeImg()` and on and on until Angular gets bored of you and crashes your app.

If the call stack size error hadn't occurred you'd be passing the result of `this.changeImg()` to `setTimeout`, instead of passing a *reference* to a function as expected.

Simply remove the invocation.

```
setTimeout(this.changeImg, time);
```

Comment: how can I use set timeout or setinterval in ngOninit so I can repeat that function over and over
or what is the best practice to do so?

Comment: Your approach is fine if you remove the invocation from `changeImg` as I've suggested. As for what is best practice I can't say, but I personally think it's clearer if you set an interval inside of `ngOnInit` instead of having `changeImg` continually set a timeout. Remember that both `setTimer` and `setInterval` expect a function reference, so don't invoke `this.changeImg`: `setInterval(this.changeImg, 1000)`

Comment: Everyone has to learn at first, my dude. The important part is that you asked the question instead of giving up or blaming Angular.